# CPU consumption when thead is sleeping

Tags: java, multithreading, jakarta-mail, cpu-usage

I have a system where I have multiple threads running ( less than 10 ) which keep on checking if a new email message has been received for an email address. The code sleeps when no message in Inbox for every 5 seconds and checks for any new message in a loop. I am getting 100% CPU utilization after the code runs for a extended period (a few hours or a day) even when there are no messages in the Inbox of the email. I am using Javax.mail for connecting to gmail.

I have tried reducing the number of threads, increasing the wait time etc.

```
while (!this.isThreadInterrupt) {
    if (this.getMessageCount() > 0) {
        //do something  
    } else {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you for the help in advance

Comment: Take a thread dump and see what's running and not blocked or sleeping.  If you're using thread interrupts, you need to clear the interrupted state or it will "stick".

Comment: I am not using thread interrupts, I do not see a problem with thread dump as well

Comment: @d_void Please post the contents of `this.getMessageCount()`.  Is the `this.isThreadInterrupt` declared volatile?